# My page goes to the onclick event before submit

Tags: javascript, c#, html, onclick, submit

I have used submit and added an onclick event to it and I want to call the controller method save for it, and after that I want to redirect my page to another method of the controller for that I have used onclick where I have used `opener.href = ""`. My problem is that sometimes it goes to the save page but oftenly it goes to the onclick event first. I have searched it on google and all the methods tell me to the way I did but something is not right. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
<input id="m_bs_btnNext" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="closeWindow();" />
```

and the onclick function is:

```
function closeWindow() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.opener.location.href = "ViewDesign";
        setTimeout("window.close()", 800);
    }
```

Comment: Can you just use `onsubmit` on your form to close the window? That way you can guarantee the save happens first.

Comment: Or make an Ajax request instead of a standard form submit, and then wait until the response comes back to do the redirect.

Comment: Iam using model, priorly i used ajax but since i have a viewmodel here so iam using a submit.

Answer (score 0):

I would have your close window happen after the save by using `onsubmit` on your form:

```
<form id="form" action="/save" onsubmit="saveAndCloseWindow()">
   <-- Other form elements -->
   <input id="m_bs_btnNext" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="closeWindow();" />
</form>
```

Then your save function would look like this:

```
function saveAndCloseWindow() {
    $.ajax({
       url: $('#form').attr('action'),
       method: 'POST',
       success: function() {
         window.opener.location.reload();
         window.opener.location.href = "ViewDesign";
         setTimeout("window.close()", 800);
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: I used this method before but I don't want to use ajax here as I have a viewmodel here and I have to pass the model to the save method of my controller. After that save method is hit by the submit then Iam putting this onclick event where the page after saving calls the onclick and the onclick calls a viewdesign method and closes the popup.

Comment: You'll need to have the page that is rendered after you submit your form call the JavaScript to close the window then.

Comment: Any other suggestions please!